# How to add body(content) in google document of google drive by using apex

Tags: rest, google-drive-api, google-docs, apex, google-docs-api

We want to create a google document in google drive. And want to add data into a google document.
We are now creating the file in the drive but the body(content) of the document is not getting added.

Below is the code used for creating a file

```
public static void createDocument(String folderId, String documentName) {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+accessToken);
    req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    req.setTimeout(60*1000);
    String body = '{"title":"'+ documentName +'.txt","parents":[{"id":"'+ folderId +'"}],"body": {"content": "Text of document"}}';
    req.setBody(body);
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
}
```

So can you please help us.

Answer (score 1):

> We want to create a google document in google drive.

To create a document in Google drive you should be using Google drive API v3 [create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) method files are created in two parts the metadata followed by the file stream.  You appear to be trying to add the contents of the file as part of the metadata. it is not part of the metadata it must be uploaded as a file stream.  [manage upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

> And want to add data into a google document.

You need to understand that the Google drive api is a file storage api only it has no ability's to write to the file itself.  For that you should be using the Google Documents api which will allow you to write to a google doc file.

> We are now creating the file in the drive but the body(content) of the document is not getting added.

You are also using the google drive v2 you should consider switching to google drive v3.

Comment: @DalmTo  Thank you for your response. Can we do this by using Google drive API for any version v2 or v3? But we want to use Google Drive API instead of Google docs API.

Comment: Then create the file on your machine and upload the file directly though the Google drive api.   You apear to be using C# Why not use the Google .net client library

Comment: The file content is dynamic & different for each document. I am using the apex programming language in salesforce.

Comment: Why can't you use Google Docs API? Could you show an example of how you obtain the content of a single document?

Comment: @Darshana then you need to use the google docs api its designed for writing to google doc's.   Google drive just a file storage system thats all.

Comment: I am trying to create a doc by using google docs API but getting an error **System.CalloutException: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents** & my code is `HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint('https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+accessToken);
        String body='{"title": "Test"}';
        req.setBody(body);
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);`

Comment: If you have a new question please open a new question and include your code i would be happy to have a look

Comment: Hi @DaImTo Please check the question. Link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67815831/how-to-solve-system-calloutexception-unauthorized-endpoint-please-check-setup