# How to solve System.CalloutException: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings for Google docs API

Tags: rest, salesforce, apex, google-docs-api

I am getting

> System.CalloutException: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents

error while creating document in drive.

Here is my code

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint('https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+accessToken);
    req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    req.setTimeout(60*1000);
    String body='{"title": "NewDocument"}';
    req.setBody(body);
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
```

Can you please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error gives you the steps to solve this.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.configuring_remoteproxy.htm&type=5

You need to tell Salesforce it's OK to make a call to that URL by following the steps in the article above.